# How to Describe "Use case Diagram" in formal style?

Tags: uml

How to Describe "Use case Diagram" in formal style?

Anyone have template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by "describe a use case diagram" describing each use case individually, there is a "[procedure](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/5383.html)" in RUP methodology.

CASE tools like [Enterprise Architect](http://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) or [MagicDraw](http://www.magicdraw.com/) support it by built-in forms for specifying preconditions (what must be fulfilled before the use case takes place), postconditions (what is fulfilled after taking place) and scenarios (what is particular flow of events or actions, and it alternatives) etc.

But if you are serious about describing your use case, filling all its details into those tiny forms is quite uncomfortable and not-providing-easy-survey. You may produce a .rtf generated by the tool from your use case model (providing a template already present in the tools, usually not very good-looking:).

Another way (and my preferred) is describing use cases in a separate Word document by hand (and paste the use case diagram into it). [This guy](http://alistair.cockburn.us/) wrote an amazing book "Writing effective use cases". I personally recommend it to everyone coping with use cases in his every day job. [Here](http://www.johnmichaelbattista.me/software-engineering/use-cases) you can find a "compressed" guidelines extracted from the book.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of the UML drawing packages will have templates for UC diagram. For example see "dia" or eclipse with modelling framework

Other non-free tools include MS visio, MagicDraw and so many more

Comment: Describe each use case ?